# How can I import the Google API Objective-C Client Library in to my iOS project without getting errors?

Tags: ios, google-api-objc-client

Ok. I've followed all the steps on [Google's API page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary). I am trying to interact with Blogger's api and I'm getting exactly 9 Apple Mach-O Linker errors.
How can I import the library and get everything set up and NOT get those errors? Thanks!

Here's the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLService", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLServiceBlogger in GTLBlogger_Sources.o
 (maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLServiceBlogger)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLService", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceBlogger in GTLBlogger_Sources.o
 (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceBlogger)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLObject", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerPage in GTLBloggerPage.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerPageAuthor in GTLBloggerPage.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerPageBlog in GTLBloggerPage.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerPageAuthorImage in GTLBloggerPage.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerBlog in GTLBloggerBlog.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerBlogLocale in GTLBloggerBlog.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerBlogPages in GTLBloggerBlog.o
  ...
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQuery", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQueryBlogger in GTLBlogger_Sources.o
 (maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQueryBlogger)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLCollectionObject", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerPageList in GTLBloggerPageList.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerPostList in GTLBloggerPostList.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerBlogPosts in GTLBloggerBlog.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerPostReplies in GTLBloggerPost.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerCommentList in GTLBloggerCommentList.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBloggerBlogList in GTLBloggerBlogList.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLObject", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerPage in GTLBloggerPage.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerPageAuthor in GTLBloggerPage.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerPageBlog in GTLBloggerPage.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerPageAuthorImage in GTLBloggerPage.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerBlog in GTLBloggerBlog.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerBlogLocale in GTLBloggerBlog.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerBlogPages in GTLBloggerBlog.o
  ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQuery", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryBlogger in GTLBlogger_Sources.o
 (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryBlogger)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLCollectionObject", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerPageList in GTLBloggerPageList.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerPostList in GTLBloggerPostList.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerBlogPosts in GTLBloggerBlog.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerPostReplies in GTLBloggerPost.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerCommentList in GTLBloggerCommentList.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBloggerBlogList in GTLBloggerBlogList.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: If you want help you need to post the linker errors.

Comment: Will do! Expect an edit in the question.

Comment: ok just added the error to the question

Comment: Most likely when you added the files to your project you did not set the target membership for the associated .m files. Select the `GTLService.m` and other GTL .m files and make sure their target membership is set properly.

Comment: I just checked and their targets are all set to my app target.

Comment: It's still not working.

Comment: Make sure that you have the armv7 architecture included in your build settings under "Architectures"

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I seem to get it working now.

Comment: What is the error, can you tell us

Comment: I am getting the same errors, what you do to fix these, thanks

Comment: I've checked all the above and I still have the same problem. I'm using the Google Drive SDK with Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1

Comment: A year later and I'm having the same problem.  What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just quote what @borrrden already wrote. This worked for me.

> Make sure that you have the armv7 architecture included in your build settings under "Architectures"

Comment: I've done that, but it still gives me the same linker error. I am using the Google Drive SDK and Xcode 6.1 with iOS 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem just like you. I solve by check all the steps again .
I found the problem.HAHA!

**Build phases** --> **Link Binary With Libraries**

at there all the framework disappeared after running the code! So what you have to do is add the framework again.

Please add the framework as follows:
**libGTLTouchStaticLib.a  + Security.framework + SystemConfiguration.framework + MobileCoreServices.framework**